# SQL metal to dbml, how to generate correct foreign key column names

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I  have this  2 tables

table name: **Person** with Columns:**PersonID, Name**

table name: **VisitInfo** with Columns: **VisitPersonID , CoordinatorPersonID**

both columns have a foreign key to person table

When i generate the code i get a VisitInfo class with the properties:

- Person
- CoordinatorPerson

But what i want is a VisitInfoClass with the following properties:

- VisitPerson
- CoordiniatorPerson

When generating the code file, sql metal begins to refer to the collumn name only for the second foreign key to the same table.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would:
VisitInfo.PersonByVisitPersonID
VisitInfo.PersonByCoordinatorPersonID
...be any closer to what you want?

If so, my add-in for L2S has an option to use the navigation property naming style above...

You can download it from http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/